# Перезагрузить Яндекс.Карту

Tags: javascript, yandex-maps-api, яндекс-карты

Имеется код Яндекс.Карты на сайте:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
ymaps.ready(function () {
    var myMap = new ymaps.Map('map', {
            center: [lng, lat],
            zoom: 2
        }),

        myPlacemark = new ymaps.Placemark(myMap.getCenter(), {
            hintContent: '<a href="#" class="savedata" style="font-family: ddd;" onclick="goJs()">Сохранить на стену VK</a>'
        }, {
            // Опции.
            // Необходимо указать данный тип макета.
            iconLayout: 'default#image',
            // Своё изображение иконки метки.
            iconImageHref: 'mail.png',
            // Размеры метки.
            iconImageSize: [100, 100],
            // Смещение левого верхнего угла иконки относительно
            // её "ножки" (точки привязки).
            iconImageOffset: [-3, -42]
        });

    myMap.geoObjects.add(myPlacemark);    

});
</script>
```

После выполнения функции координаты `lng` и `lat` меняются, а на карте изменений не происходит. Как лучше поступить?

Comment: Эти переменные меняются, а каким образом вы передаете новые значения?
Если никак, то понятное дело, что не поменяется карта, т.к. вы изменяете значение переменной а не свойства объекта карты.
P.S. дайте больше данных о работе скрипта. Как вы меняете значения этих переменных

Comment: В Json получаю координаты и все. Может просто перезагрузить div с картой? Если да, то как это сделать на jquery?

Answer (score 1):

Нужно сообщить карте что вы хотите изменить

- если центр карты то вызывайте [myMap.setCenter](https://yandex.ru/dev/maps/archive/doc/jsapi/2.0/ref/reference/Map.html#method_detail__setCenter)
- если место отметки то [myPlacemark.geometry.setCoordinates](https://yandex.ru/dev/maps/archive/doc/jsapi/2.0/ref/reference/geometry.Point.html)